# Custom js button throws error after class version change

Tags: apex, custom-button

I am trying to migrate classes from an older API version to a moderately higher version, while doing so I came across a JS button which calls an apex method and creates a record. This has stopped working when I change the version number of the class from 26 to 40 and I get a error message as show in the screenshot below. But when I revert the version back to 26 it works well. I also tried to check the considerations and forward compatibility of these JS buttons but I wasn't able to find any article on it. I have also added the code for your reference. Can someone let me know how to fix it?

[image: SOAP Fault error message]

```
JS Button :
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/apex.js")}

var oppId= "{!Opportunity.Id }";
var accId= "{!Opportunity.AccountId}";
var url = parent.location.href;


//sforce.debug.trace=true;

var status = sforce.apex.execute("NewQuoteRequestHelper2", "createResquest", {a:oppId, b:accId});
//sforce.debug.trace=true;
if( status == 'true'){
parent.location.href = url;
}

Apex class :
global class NewQuoteRequestHelper2{
         
         webservice static string createResquest (Id oppId, Id accId){
              string ret = 'false';
              //Opportunity o= [SELECT AccountId, ContactId, Id, _Name__c, Status, Subject, Type, Date_Due__c, Origin FROM Case where id=: oppId];
              case c= new case();
              c.AccountId= accId;
              c.Opportunity_Name__c= oppId;
              c.Status= 'Not Started';
              c.Subject='Please Generate Quote'; 
              //c.Type="Request Quote" ;
              c.Date_Due__c= system.today();
              c.Origin='Opportunity';
              insert c;
              ret ='true';
              return ret;
         }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing data in the format `{a:oppId, b:accId}` and not `{oppId:oppId, accId:accId}`?

Comment: Actually, the button was coded that way and it was working. I changed the parameter names to oppId and accId and they are working now, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX toolkit allowing calls to Apex through `sforce.apex.execute()` must be used with the following parameters.

`sforce.apex.execute(ClassName, MethodName, InputData)`. The execute method takes primitive data types, sObjects, and lists of primitives or sObjects. Here, `InputData` can be an empty object OR an object defining key-value pairs  where the key **always** matches the Apex method input parameter name.

`NewQuoteRequestHelper2.createResquest (Id oppId, Id accId)` has 2 input parameters therefore the webservice request should pass an object structured as:

```
{
   oppId : <value>,
   accId : <value>
}
```

Client side call then be `var status = sforce.apex.execute("NewQuoteRequestHelper2", "createResquest",{oppId:oppId, accId:accId});`.